# After selected zoom on map result

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, geojson

I have multiple selects, one depending on the result of the other, and in the end I need it to zoom in on the area I searched and found. However it is not working.

the source code is here:

https://github.com/eltonsantos/leaflet-tests/blob/master/teste3/index.html

[image: Problem with zoom]

I tried it:

```
$("#numSearch").on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);
        map.fitBounds(e.getBounds());
    });
```

But dont work. Someone help me please? Ps: Sorry for my bad english

---

EDIT

I tried:

```
$("#numSearch").on('change', function(e) {

        var value = $(this).find(':selected').val();
        var boundArea = value.target;
        map.fitBounds(boundArea.getBounds());


    });
```

Where value return 74 in string format
but dont work, get a error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBounds' of undefined
```

Comment: What is the value of `e` inside that event handler?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: e.getBounds is not a function

Comment: You can clone my project, its just a html and js, dont need install nothing

Comment: That's an error message, that's not the *value* of `e`. What happens if you do a `console.log(e)` inside the event handler?

Comment: The result is toooo long! r.Event {originalEvent: Event, type: "change", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, target: select#numSearch.form-control, currentTarget: select#numSearch.form-control, …} (...too long...)  Object

Comment: And that looks like an [`Event` of type `change` coming from the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change), right?

Comment: Yes! I need that when selecting something in the input of the select, the map zooms in the selected location. Example, I select sector 78 in the input select, there the map will zoom in sector 78.

Comment: You realize that `e` is a browser event that's telling you (e.g.) "the user has switched the `<select>` to number 78", and it's **not** the Leaflet polygon for sector 78, right?

Comment: Yep, I realised

Comment: I just wanna on select result in input select, show in map with zoom. The select work fine, but I cant the zoom :(

Comment: So the question you should be asking yourself is: given a `change` event, that contains the number of an area/polygon, how do I get a reference to that polygon, so I can call `.getBounds()` on that polygon.

Comment: Unfortunately I spent the afternoon trying and have not got it yet, even using the getbounds in the result obtained by select, for example, the 74 :(

Comment: How can I get continue with my question and I got answers from other people adding more information to my previous question?I now have the result from the select, but it came in string format through var value = $(this).find(':selected').val(); It return 74, in string format. I tried value.getBounds() but dont work

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrease your minZoom first before you can properly test if your code works. I can't tell for just your screen but the map won't fit the bounds correctly if the selected area is bigger than the bounds of the screen at the min zoom.

I just looked through your code more. try changing your on click call to this:

```
    layerStComerciais.on('click', function() {
        map.fitBounds(layerStComerciais.getBounds())
    });
```

Each of your click calls should be using the leaflet layer when calling on `getBounds()` method.

Comment: Please, can you help me? Please.

Comment: When I put: $("#numSearch").on('change', function(e){
  console.log(e);
  alert(e.fitBounds());

 });

I receive: Uncaught TypeError: e.fitBounds is not a function

Comment: You can clone my project, its just a html and js, dont need install nothing